How can I replace this wall adapter with a power bank?
I'm looking to supply a small Freescale board (no battery or charger chip) with uninterrupted power. This is its native adapter (5V, 2A):

This is the power bank. Passthrough charging works.

When I measure the voltage on its USB port with nothing connected, I get 2.34V. I guess this is where the charger chip on a consumer device would come in and select its input voltage/current.
So am I correct in thinking I need to wire the connector through a power delivery chip like this one to get 5V 2A? Any pitfalls or other possible solutions here?
Tempted to just use a UPS but seems stupid when I have power banks with more capacity and the right voltage to do this way more efficiently and in a smaller package.

"When I measure the voltage on its USB port" which one? It's got four.

@Finbarr it has 2 USB A ports and they're labelled as 5V, 9V, 12V (this is repeated above each one). I measured one of these.

Why is this off-topic?

Technically you don't need a power delivery chip.
Many MCU boards can simply accept 5V power through USB connector and it does not require any negotiation.
USB outputs must be 5V if no further negotiation is made. If your board draws only about 1A then it should work.
The downside of powerbanks is that they tend to turn off when current is low. So it may turn off. This might be what you are measuring, the powerbank occasionally powering the USB port to see if there is a big enough load to stay on, or low enough load to stay in standby mode. Sometimes they require a button push to wake up.
Also powerbanks generally cannot be charged and provide power to a load simultaneously, so it might be that no matter which powerbank you get, you can't use it as a 5V UPS by connecting it between a USB mains adapter and your MCU board.

Passthrough charging (with load) does work on these. I tried pressing the button, same thing. So would you say it's at least safe to connect the board? I've done this with a Pi Zero before but want to be sure.

@kontextify You have a 5V USB output to a device with 5V input. Unless your device draws more than powerbank can output, or you manage to short circuit the 5V to GND, or you manage to parallel two different power supplies, you should be safe.

It does say up to 12V for USB A output on the thing, which makes me hesitate. I guess 99% chance anything higher than 5V has to be negotiated, since that's not standard?

OK, so why you are not worried that each time you plug in your mobile phone or other device that may work only up to 5V or 9V won't be damaged by 12V? This is not any different than that scenario. Yes, everything over 5V has to be negotiated on USB-A. On USB-C, even the 5V out from your powerbank needs to be negotiated.
